# creating search logic in UMBRACO 8

Tags: elasticsearch, umbraco, umbraco8, examine

I need to implement a simple business logic and query the UMBRACO CMS content from an ElasticSearch instance.

I came across two possibilities for that:

1.using the built in examarin feature with the extension package described here that support elasticsearch - https://github.com/Novicell/Novicell.Examine.ElasticSearch

2.using the plugin of elasticseach to umbraco - https://github.com/Philo/Umbraco.Elasticsearch

I know the first is more updated and the repo is more active and the later is less but it seems as the first is less flexible when it comes to business logic and coding and more black boxed.

My question is what you think suits more for my task here and why?
and do you have any more reference that can help me here?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, but curious what you have discovered thus far or which solution you went with.

Comment: Hi @hardba11 I decided to go with nest (high level SDK client) and invoke that myself.